# How can i create multiple linked lists in C for same types of data?

Tags: c

```
struct clist {
    int pos;
    char* color;
    struct clist *next;
};
typedef struct clist sl_clist;
sl_clist *head = NULL;

sl_clist* link[5];
```

So i am trying to create multiple single linked circular lists and put them into a stack, every list will have the same types of data. In this case i am using the stack as an array. But i just cannot figure out how to create multiple linked lists from single type. I am a student so i am not very experienced on C. Thaks for the help in advance.

```
void create_list (int N, sl_clist* head){
    int i;
    sl_clist *new;
    sl_clist *old;
    if(N == 0){
        head = NULL;
    }
    srand(time(0));
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        new = (sl_clist*)malloc(sizeof(sl_clist));
        if(i == 0){
            head = new;
            new -> color = color[(rand()%10)];
            new -> pos = pos[i];    
            new -> next = head;
        }
        else{
            new -> color = color[(rand()%10)];
            new -> pos = pos[i];    
            old -> next = new;
            new -> next = head;
        }
        old = new;
    }
}
```

I have also tried creating multiple "head" variables but for some reason when i use them in this function(just imagine there are arrays for color and pos) they always return NULL.

Comment: Q: how to create multiple linked lists...and put them into a stack?  A:  Simple.  Instead of having a single variable `sl_clist *head`, each element in `sl_clist* link[]` is the head of a different list.   ALSO: You might want to combine `struct clist {}` and `typedef struct clist sl_clist` together into the same declaration.  Scroll down these examples to see how: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-use-the-typedef-struct-in-c

Comment: @paulsm4 Ok so i have actually tried creating multiple variables for multiple heads but this time i had trouble with using them in the function i have here. For some reason when i simply use the name of the variable instead of using it as a parameter it works. But when i use it as a parameter it stays NULL, doesn't create the list. Maybe i am not using the correct parameter type ?

Comment: It seems as if you don't have an abstract idea of the solution. Before writing code, you need to think about the algorithm and data structures. The code is just the final step. If you are clear with the abstract part, things like parameter types come naturally. So this is my advice: step back from the code, take a pencil and some pieces of paper and solve the task on a higher level.

Comment: [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) - you can create as many `list_t` type lists as you like.

Comment: This is a problem: `void create_list (int N, sl_clist* head){}`.  PROBLEM: *head is only updated INSIDE of the function.  The caller never sees the change.  SOLUTION: `void create_list (int N, sl_clist **head){}`.  This article might help explain: https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx8.html

Answer (score 1):

Do not use global variables. Remove them.

```
sl_clist *head = NULL;
sl_clist* link[5];
```

Using local varaibles will "force" you to use a modular design that supports multiple lists.

Variables are passed by value:

```
    head = new;
```

modifies **a copy** `sl_clist* head` of the original pointer passed as the argument. The original pointer **is unaffected**.

There are multiple ways you can solve that problem. You can return the new value:

```
 sl_clist *create_list (int N, sl_clist* head){
       ...
       return new; // or old value
 }
int main() {
   sl_clist *head = NULL;
   head = create_list(5, head);
}
```

You can take the pointer by reference:

```
int create_list (int N, sl_clist **head){
      ...
      *head = new; // set new value
      (*head)->something = something; // be aware of operator precedence
}
int main() {
   sl_clist *head = NULL;
   create_list(5, &head);    // head is getting modified
}
```

But I recommend doing a separate type for the head. That way the function is clear - it takes *the head*, specifically, not any list element. Be verbose:

```
struct sl_head {
    struct clist *head;
};
int create_list(int N, struct sl_head *head) {
    //                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^ - verbose, this is the head, not some element, less mistakces
    head->head = new;   // a bit more to type
    head->head->something = something; 
}

int main() {
    struct sl_head head = {0};  // no longer a pointer
    create_list(5, &head);      // head is getting modified
}
```

Move `srand(time(0));` to `main()`. It's not a function that you call when creating a list.